# Placing int inside built function don't change image of dice , but when move it to above @override it works , dice image change .Why?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dicee'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int leftDice = 1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  leftDice = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDice.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("rightbutton");
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice2.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am learning to make dice bars as I am beginner in flutter.
Placing integer inside built function don't change image of dice , but when I moves it to above @override it works , dice image starts changing onpressed . Please explain this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because build method is executed on `setState()`. If you declare and initialize `leftDice` **inside** build method, changing the value on `setState()` won't change anything because it will re-declared and re-initialized **inside** build method. If you declare and initialize it **outside** build method, when you change the value of `leftDice` in `setState()`, the value won't get re-initialized therefore the UI will change with the newest value of `leftDice`.

inside build method flow:

```
int leftDice = 1; // initializing
setState(() => leftDice = 2); // changing the value of leftDice
leftDice = 2; // getting new value
// but build method is called after calling setState(() {})
// therefore leftDice is re-initialized
int leftDice = 1;
// rebuild UI with leftDice = 1
```

outside build method flow:

```
int leftDice = 1; // initializing
setState(() => leftDice = 2); // changing the value of leftDice
leftDice = 2; // getting new value
// build method is called after calling setState(() {})
// but this time leftDice doesn't get re-initialized and maintaining its new value
// rebuild UI with new value
```

Comment: Thanks federick , for guiding me.

Comment: @Nishant If you find an answer is correct or helpful, you can mark it as correct answer so people who view this question know the question is already answered and has a correct answer.

Comment: I need a little bit more explanation , ie what is the function of build state here and relationship between build and set state.

Comment: @Nishant A Widget class whether stateless or stateful always call the build method returning a Widget. If the components in that Widget class has a function calling setState method, Flutter will re-call that build method to rebuild the UI. So in short, calling setState means you re-call the build method.

Comment: @Nishant You are welcome. Once again tho, if you find an answer helpful or fulfill your question, don't forget to give it a check mark to inform others that this question already has an accepted answer.